# file_get_html multiple times in the same script

Tags: php

I am using simple html dom parser. When I am requesting a page like `file_get_html()` I am getting 2 values. One is title and the other one is an url. Within this I want to do `file_get_html()` again.

But I am getting similar data for the second traverse.

Like this script :

```
foreach($urls as $value) {
  $html=file_get_html($value);
  
  foreach($html->find('div[class=data] a') as $content) {
       $url2='http://abc.com/'.$content->href;
       $childHtml=file_get_html($url2);

       echo $childHtml; //Proble is here i am getting the previous data-->html
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

## This is the main crawling code

```
$urls=GenerateURLS($currentmonth);     
$tracker=0;
$urlHolderArray=array();

foreach ($urls as $value) {
  $html=file_get_html($value);  //Here I am requesting the html dom

  foreach ($html->find('div[id=centrepanel] div[class=events_listing_container]  div[class=events_info_container] div[class=events_image] a') as $content) {
    $proxyURL="http://www.junkclub.com/".$content->href;
    array_push($urlHolderArray,$proxyURL);          
  }
}

echo '<pre/>';
print_r($urlHolderArray);
echo '<pre/>';

foreach ($urlHolderArray as $link) {
  $htmlCon=file_get_html($link);
}

echo $htmlCon;
```

Comment: `foreach($urls as $link) { $html=file_get_html($value); // ...` - should this not read `$html=file_get_html($link);`? Although I doubt it would fix the problem. What is the value of `$link`? It looks to me as if you are assuming that all the `href` URLs are relative, but they may not be... Try `echo $url2;` and load it in a browser - does it give the result you expect?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake while i typed..check it now...actually the us a simple one url.and i need to send another get html on that url.Can we do it?

Comment: Yes it can be done but I suspect you problem here is that `$url2` does not contain what you think it does... What do you see when you `echo $url2;`?

Comment: yes it does...I am updating with the original code...